# Is it possible to run linux config command from asp .net app

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible exec linux command from asp.net core website?
Something like

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I mean I need configure PC use web UI like in routers

Answer (score 1):

You need to add dependency to System.Diagnostics.Process  [API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netcore-1.1)

Then you can execute a bash command like this.  **Please treat this as a pseudo code as I am not near a Linux machine to test this out**

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "/bin/bash";
        psi.Arguments = "-c sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0";
        psi.UseShellExecute = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = psi
        };

        proc.Start();
```